# Android: column not found

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm making my first steps with android and databases. at the moment i have the problem that android keeps telling me that my column doesn't exist and i don't know why.

E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table positions has no column named latitude

This is where i create my Database

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
    try{
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE + " (ID integer primary key autoincrement,name varchar(255),longitude long,latitude long)");            
    }
```

And this is where i'm trying to add my datas

```
 myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("longitude",longi);
        values.put("latitude",lati);

        myDB.insert(MY_DB_TABLE,null,values);
        myDB.close();
```

Hoping to find some help :/

Comment: Your DB creation clause contains _longitude_ , within addition you have _lonitude_ .

Comment: `lonitude`? and did you check if that table actually has a latitude field? YOu may have an old copy running around that doesn't, which WON'T be added since you're doing `if not exists`.

Comment: Oh god damn... am i so blind? oO I'm sorry sorry for my stupidity

Comment: @MarcB I did it again without `if not exists` now it is telling me there is no column longitude oO I fixed the typo btw

Comment: Uninstall you app and run it again. As @MarcB pointed out you probably still have the old version of the database. Uninstall will delete it and create a new on with all the columns.

Comment: @CarlosJ I did but still ... `E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table positions has no column named longitude` :(

Comment: `if not exists` skips the creation if (go figure) the table already exists. simply removing `not exists` won't do much, now you'd just get a duplicate table error. you'd have to `DROP` the table, THEN `CREATE` it again.

Comment: @MarcB i removed the app from the device and reinstalled it, this should delete the database too or am i wrong?